# Rendering Index Html With Slim Framework

Tags: php, slim

I am developing a REST API with Slim Framework. I want to make a GET request, where the html index of the page will sent to the client, for this I made the following code.

main.php

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Slim\Views\PhpRenderer;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Slim\App();
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['renderer'] = new PhpRenderer("../public");

$app->get('/', function(Request $request, Response $response){
    return $this->renderer->render($response, "index.html");
});

$app->run();
```

here is my project structure

```
├───images
├───oracle
│   ├───main.php
│   ├───queries
│   └───vendor
│       └───slim
├───public
│   ├───index.html
│   ├───images
│   ├───javascripts
│   ├───libraries
│   └───styles
├───resources
└───test
```

So my problem is that at the time of making the request it only import the html and doesn't its dependencies. Also I tried with require the public directory into the main.php, but it threw the next error:

```
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\ImportedPapers\public): failed to open stream: Permission denied in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\ImportedPapers\oracle\main.php on line 11

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../public' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
C:\xampp\htdocs\ImportedPapers\oracle\main.php on line 11
```

Finally, I'm developing on Windows. I was investigating about the previous error and found that could be a permissions error, but I already enabled the directory with modality "total control" in all users. I do not think the problem is a bad html statement, because if I run it separately, it renders me well.

Any idea what it might be.

Comment: `require(C:\xampp\htdocs\ImportedPapers\public)` suggests it's trying to require a directory rather than a file.

Comment: Yes, the first require is for the execution of Slim. But I try with the absolute path and the same error persists. @Álvaro Gonzáles

Comment: Excuse me, I'm new in this language. It was in error into the HTML, because as you can see in the structure of the project, I am invoking the html from another directory and the dependencies were defined with relative path in the HTML directory. Then it could not find it.